# Display Powershell Variables in GUI

Tags: powershell, user-interface, vbscript

I have a bit of PowerShell logic that displays variables for users, however the method I'm currently using displays the information in a very small window. I would like to know of a method that allows me to modify the size of the window, the size of the text and possibly add color. Does anyone know how to do this with PowerShell or VBS?

Current Script:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Today's Dates

5 Days Old - $5day
4 Days Old - $4day
3 Days Old - $3day
")
```

Comment: Start [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stephap/2012/04/23/building-forms-with-powershell-part-1-the-form/)

Comment: For anybody looking to make a GUI for a PowerShell script I strongly suggest FoxDeploy's guide ([link](https://foxdeploy.com/series/learning-gui-toolmaking-series/)). I recommend starting at Part 1 of the XAML and Visual Studio section. This lets you visually design your GUI in Visual Studio, customize it how you want, and then tweak it in PowerShell if desired.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician This is a really helpful guide. Wish I could upvote twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment an answer, despite the fact that it's a link, for better visibility. As previously mentioned, I would strongly suggest the [XAML GUI guide](https://foxdeploy.com/series/learning-gui-toolmaking-series/) written by FoxDeploy.

All credit goes to FoxDeploy (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238413/foxdeploy) for the excellent walk through of how to create a functional GUI for your PowerShell scripts.

Also included in that guide is some great info and links regarding multi-threading scripts using runspace pools.

Comment: Took me a couple days, but the guide allowed me to essentially make an app that does what I want with my PS Script. Thanks again @TheMadTechnician

Answer (score 0):

This is an HTA file. It can contain JScript/VBScript and HTML. This sets the clipboard and then inserts the clipboard into the document.

```
   <html>
    <body bgcolor="cornflowerblue">
    <h1>My Heading</h1>
    <p style=color:antiquewhite>My Paragraph</p>
    <script language=vbscript>
    document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData "TEXT", "Myyt"
    document.write document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great script, but do you have any idea how I would pipe the PowerShell variables into this?